# Ajax Control Toolkit Vertical Labels

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have this chart, see below. The data is just rubbish but shows the problem. The Axis label of countries over laps. Is there any way to rotate them ? A bit like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/ye3usuhu/)

Yes I know I could just shorten or abbreviate the names but that kind of defeats the point.

I tried a stacked chart but then the left margin is too small to display the text.

Any help would be very much appreciated

[image: chart1 1][image]

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" ></asp:ScriptManager>
    <ajaxToolkit:PieChart ID="PieChart1" runat="server" ChartWidth="500px" ChartHeight="400px" ></ajaxToolkit:PieChart><br />
    <ajaxToolkit:BarChart ID="BarChart1" runat="server"    Width="1000px" ChartHeight="400px" ></ajaxToolkit:BarChart>

    <ajaxtoolkit:barchart id="BarChart2" runat="server"
                                chartheight="300"       chartwidth="450"
                                charttype="Column" charttitle="Sample chart title"
                                categoriesaxis="United Kingdom,United States,Australia,New Zealand,United Arab Emirates,Switzerland"
                                charttitlecolor="#0E426C" categoryaxislinecolor="#D08AD9"
                                valueaxislinecolor="#D08AD9" baselinecolor="#A156AB">
           <Series>
                     <ajaxToolkit:BarChartSeries Name="United States" BarColor="#6C1E83"
                                                               Data="110, 189, 255, 95, 107, 140" />

           </Series>
</ajaxtoolkit:barchart>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate this text labels manually. Something like this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<!-- some barchart code here -->
<script>
    $(function() {
        var barChartID= "<%= BarChart1.ClientID %>";

        var $svg = $("#" + barChartID).find("svg"); // SVG BarChart element
        var $series = $svg.find("text[id=SeriesAxis]"); // labels to rotate

        $series.each(function(index, element) {
            var $element = $(element);

            // we need to remove x and y attributes and add translation
            // so we can rotate the element correctly
            var x = $element.attr("x");
            var y = +$element.attr("y") + 10;

            $element.removeAttr("x");
            $element.removeAttr("y");
            $element.attr("transform", "translate(" + x + ", " + y + ") rotate(-45)");
        });
    });
</script>
```